# Can't install Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

First, [I asked this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566847/cant-install-windows-after-ubuntu) but it was suggested to me to ask here as well.

I installed Ubuntu and now I removed Ubuntu to install windows 7. I removed and created a partition using the Windows installer, the Ubuntu installer and using gparted with NTFS as file system. But I’m always getting into the same error.

There's nothing connected to the computer unless the Windows CD. At command prompt, I’ve already used Diskpart to clean the partition I’ve created.

The Windows CD I’m using is working, I’ve already tested it in other PC.

It’s possible to reinstall Ubuntu, but not Windows. I tried to install in a HDD.

Was tested gpt and dos HDD partition table. Didn't work too. Here is the error:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computers hardware may
>   not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disks controller is
>   enabled in the computers BIOs menu.

There are some few questions like mine, but the solutions given to them don’t seem to work for me.

Comment: Make sure secure boot is disabled in BIOS

Comment: I don't have this option. My BIOS is very simple.

Comment: Go back into the Ubuntu live cd, delete the partition but DO NOT make a new one, leave it as free space

Comment: Tried. Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: What motherboard do you have, and do you have an option for UEFI / normal booting ?  It sounds to me like your motherboard is trying to do a UEFI boot, and the BIOS has an instruction to boot Grub (ie Linux), but not Windows.

Comment: Since your BIOS doesn't do secure boot the next thing I would try is to use gparted to create a new partition table (device menu)

Comment: Do you see the harddrive when you try to install? If not this may be an driver issue. As well you could try to turn off/on the HD AHCI Mode in bios.

Comment: I don't have UEFI/normal booting option. I've already created a new partition table (GPT and DOS), didn't work. I can see the HD, I can even install Ubuntu in it, but not Windows. It's a notebook Sony Waio VPCF136FM, link: http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VPCF136FM&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=manuals#/manualsTab

Comment: @xR34P3Rx I tried your suggestion again and It worked!! You can put as asnwer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back into the Ubuntu live cd, delete the partition but DO NOT make a new one, leave it as free space